# Знатоки, объясните, пожалуйста кусочек кода javascript

Tags: javascript

не понимаю, почему в root записалось столько значений, по коду для меня получалось, что записаться должны были данные с parent - 0

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, parent: 0, text: "Top-level comment 1" },
  { id: 2, parent: 0, text: "Top-level comment 2" },
  { id: 3, parent: 2, text: "Top-level comment 3" },
  { id: 4, parent: 3, text: "Top-level comment 4" },
]

function restructureArray() {
  const dataMap = {};
  const root = [];

  data.forEach(item => {
    dataMap[item.id] = {
      ...item,
      children: [],
    }
  });
  data.forEach(item => {
    const parent = dataMap[item.parent];
    if (parent) {
      //console.log(parent);
      parent.children.push(dataMap[item.id]);
    } else {
      root.push(dataMap[item.id]);
    }

  });
  return root;
}

const result = restructureArray();

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 1))
```

Comment: так там и записаны они самые.......а для них записаны соответствующие дети......... если вам они не нужны, то следует убрать код `parent.children.push(dataMap[item.id]);`

Comment: Алексей прав, ваш код правильный. Функция руструктурирует ваш массив, просто показывает дочерние элементы, из-за чего скорее вы запутались и подумали что код неверный. Массив root содержит 2 элемента.

Comment: код работает ровно так, как и написан =)

Comment: мне нужно, чтобы кто-нибудь объяснил как раз строчку parent.children.push(dataMap[item.id]);